# How to keep different font sizes on the same base line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making this work by adding a `margin-bottom` on my small word container but I was hoping there was another elegant/responsive approach to this.

**Things I've tried:**

1. I've tried `align-items: baseline` with flexbox but it only takes
   the first word and puts it on the baseline and everything else is
   under the line.
2. Position absolute everything and use margin's/floats.  Takes a lot of
   effort to maintain with different screen sizes.

fid: http://jsfiddle.net/1d4pqvc6/1/

html:

```
 <div class="main">
  <span class="big">BIG</span>
  <span class="small">
    <span class="word">Sony A7III</span>
    <span class="word">16-35mm and 85mm</span>
    <span class="word">Nikon D810</span>
    <span class="word">Landscape and Moments</span>
    <span class="word">Photography and Film</span>
  </span>
  <div class="big">WORD</div>
</div>

<div class="line"></div>
```

css:

```
.center-title{
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 60%; */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  height: 300px;
  }
  
  
.main{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: initial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;




}
 
  .small{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: "Crimson Text";
    font-style: italic;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-end;
   margin-bottom: 32px;
    }
 .big{
    font-size: 13rem;
    font-family: Jost;
    display: inline-block;

    line-height: 13rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;

  }
      .word{
      line-height: 1rem;
    }
  .line{
position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 2px;
    top: 184px;
  }
```

Comment: please try justify-content when you use flex

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want the baselines of BIG, Photography and Film and WORD to be the same? And the whole line to be centered vertically and horizontally? Is that correct?

Comment: @AHaworth That is correct but the centered vertically doesn't really matter to me, just the horizontal